# Как реализовать метод, "убивающий" объекты?

Tags: объекты, методы

Допустим, есть класс Животные. От него наследуются 2 класса: Хищники и Травоядные. Можно ли реализовать метод в классе Хищники, вызов которого будет "убивать"
 объекты класса Травоядные.

Comment: А почему бы и нет, в принципе реализовать то можно что угодно

Comment: Можете просто в класс добавить булево поле `isAlive`.

Comment: О, это мысль. Благодарю.

Comment: Если ваш язык поддерживает детерминистическую деаллокацию объектов, такой метод скорее всего имеет названия _деструктор_.

Comment: @VladD, нехорошо же деструктор вызывать...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, деструктор обычно нужно вызывать через оператор `delete`.

Comment: Встретились два зверька и один вызвал delete второго? А как тот, кто его создал, об этом узнать должен?

Comment: @Qwertiy: На мой вкус `delete` должна вызывать бизнес-логика, а не конкретные объекты.

Comment: @VladD волк съел овцу - вполне себе бизнес логика. А вот узнать о том, что животное уже съели - никак нельзя.

Comment: Не, «съел овцу» в терминах бизнес-логики это не просто удаление объекта. Об этом нужно оповестить хлев (чтобы он освободил место), пастуха (чтобы он не искал её больше), возможно, вычеркнуть из других списков тоже. А что именно нужно сделать — этим пусть бизнес-логика и занимается.

Comment: @VladD после съедения овца переходит в состояние "мертвая", а не удаляется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А после того, как её съедят, в состояние «съеденная»?

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, на С++ можно реализовать что-то вроде

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Food {
    Food() { cout << "Food constructor" << endl; }
    ~Food() { cout << "Food destructor" << endl; }
};
struct Predator {
    void eat(Food& food) { food.~Food(); }
    void eat(Food* food) { delete food; }
};

int main()
{
    Predator p;
    Food *f1 = new Food;
    Food *f2 = new Food;
    p.eat(*f1);
    p.eat(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Но, имхо, это плохо. Есть можно только динамически созданную еду). Хотя можно обезопасить себя от UB, запретив создание объектов Food на стеке:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Food {
    Food() { cout << "Food constructor" << endl; }
    void die() { delete this; }
private:
    ~Food() { cout << "Food destructor" << endl; }
};
struct Predator {
    void eat(Food& food) { food.die(); }
    void eat(Food* food) { food->die(); }
};

int main()
{
    Predator p;
    Food *f1 = new Food;
    Food *f2 = new Food;
    // Food f3; --> compile time error
    p.eat(*f1);
    // delete f2; --> compile time error
    p.eat(f2);
    // f2->die(); --> а это скомпилируется, но UB, если f2 уже съеден
    return 0;
}
```

А можно и целый ззопарк развести))). Причем в данном случае, и съедение животного, и его естественная смерть совершенно безопасны, животное никак не может умереть 2 раза, глобальная функция `die` оповещает и пастуха и хлев о смерти бедняги:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Animal {
    virtual void eat(Animal*&) = 0;
    friend void ::die(Animal*&);
protected:
    virtual void die() = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() {}
};
void die(Animal*& a);

struct Sheep : public Animal
{
    Sheep() { cout << "Sheep constructor" << endl; }
    void eat(Animal*&) {/* овечка не может съесть животное */ cout << "impossible" << endl;}
protected:
    void die() { delete this; }
private:
    ~Sheep() { cout << "Sheep destructor" << endl; }
};

struct Wolf : public Animal
{
    void eat(Animal*& food) { ::die(food); }
protected:
    void die() { delete this; }
private:
    ~Wolf() {}
};

int main()
{
    Animal *s1 = new Sheep, *s2 = new Sheep, *s3 = new Sheep;
    Animal *w1 = new Wolf, *w2 = new Wolf;
    w1->eat(s1);
    w2->eat(s2);
    s3->eat(w1); // Смело...
    die(s3); // От старости... Или со страху.
    die(w1); die(w2); // Отравленные овцы?!
    // w1->die(); --> ошибка компиляции
    die(w1); // --> ничего не происходит, т.к. w1==nullptr
    cout << static_cast<void*>(w1) << endl << static_cast<void*>(s1) << endl;
    return 0;
}

void die(Animal*& a) {
    if (a != nullptr)
        a->die();
    else
        cout << "Dead animal can not die. RIP" << endl;
    a = nullptr;
}
```

Спасибо VladD за ссылки:
Вот [официальный FAQ насчёт delete this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this). А вот насчёт [явного вызова деструктора](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#dont-call-dtor-on-local) (правда, только локальной переменной).

Comment: И всё равно это плохо, просто так вызывать деструктор...

Comment: @Qwertiy мне тоже не нравится, кстати неясно почему.

Comment: @andy.37: думаю, это не разрешено по стандарту. Но не уверен, стандарт C++ — это бесконечность.

Comment: А если `w1->eat(w2)`?

Comment: @VladD, что именно не разрешено? Просто за памятью фиг уследишь, а так-то да, должно работать, вроде.

Comment: @Qwertiy волк запросто сожрет другого волка. Хотя можно кубик бросить - кто кого.

Comment: @VladD вот тут (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed) утверждается, что `delete this` - вполне законно

Comment: @andy.37: `delete this` — законно, но это совсем не то же самое, что `this->~Wolf()`.

Comment: @VladD а вот тут на `delete this` ругается компилятор (ворнингом, но тем не менее)

Comment: Вот, поправил без `this->~Wolf()`

Comment: @andy.37: Вот [официальный FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) насчёт `delete this`. А [вот](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#dont-call-dtor-on-local) насчёт явного вызова деструктора (правда, только локальной переменной).

Comment: @VladD, andy.37 Явный вызов деструктора является обратной операцией для placement new. Т.е. если для создания объекта использовался placement new - для уничтожения надо вызывать деструктор явно. Если объект создавался как-то иначе - вызывать деструктор явно не стоит.